# Simba ODBC Athena Driver failing to connect with IAM Profile authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, odbc, amazon-athena

**Driver version:** ODBC 1.1.2 for OSX
**String Connection:** `Driver=Simba Athena ODBC  Driver;AuthenticationType=IAM Profile;AWSProfile=profile-name;AwsRegion=eu-central-1;Workgroup=primary;S3OutputLocation=s3:///output;Schema=historical_data;`
**Error:** `nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 00000: [Simba][DSI] (20032) Required setting 'UID' is not present in the connection settings.`

Looks like some kind of bug in the Driver.

I can connect with AWS CLI, so the profile is properly setup.

Comment: have you set AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE variable as mentioned in https://www.simba.com/products/Athena/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/mac/content/odbc/ath/configuring/authenticating/iamprofile.htm ? And also make sure that the credentials profile is valid by looking at ~/.aws/credentials ?

Comment: `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` is only necessary if you have the credentials stored somewhere else. However, i setup the variable and still failed with the same error message.

Comment: Can you confirm if your credentials present in ~/.aws/credentials are valid ?

Comment: Yes, they are valid! it is really strange, in all this installing and uninstalling it seems that it is working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of connection with an AWS Profile is setting `AuthenticationType` to `Instance Profile`.